# How to array with Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Well I'm trying to replicate this image using geonodes in blender
[image]

But I cant figure out how to make the arrays and for some reason the array modfier does not work with the geonodes.

I only did this part:

[image]

Does anyone knows how to do that? THANKS!

Answer (score 13):

Array modifier is not working in your case because your spheres are still just instances, not real mesh. Add a *Realize Instances* node at the end, right before *Group Output* and it would work as expected. You can then use the "Object Offset" option of the Array modifier with an Empty object to easily reproduce your spiral. If you want to do everything in GeoNodes, here's one way you could:

[image]

You've already done the first part and created a rectangular array of sphere instances. I simply added a second array using a *Curve Line* to stack them vertically. *Accumulate Field* node here makes it so that the first instance in this second array is rotated 0.150rad on the Z axis, the second instance is rotated 0.300, third instance 0.450 and so on, creating a spiral.

Comment: Thanks God for Accumulating Field node :) Very nice explained.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, this is the prefect solution I was looking for, for a different problem

Answer (score 9):

you can get this:

[image]

with this node setup:

[image]