# How do you create an array of parent and child?

Tags: modifiers, parent

I want to create a group of objects that I can create an array of. Parenting the objects to an Empty doesn't work. Parenting the objects to another object doesn't work. What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: This thread might help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254166/how-to-array-with-geometry-nodes

You can use the group of objects as your input.

Comment: i would highly recommend telling us what you end goal is instead of asking for a specific technical detail which might be solved by another way a lot easier....

Comment: thanks @JamesSiewert that's very useful

Comment: @Chris Good advice. What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is a high rise building, where the individual floor is what's cloned. I'd like to be able to add or remove other meshes to the floor, ie a bike or a plant on the balcony. I'd ultimately like to add some variance to the floors as well.